# Can I deploy a java application and php application on a JBoss application server?

Tags: java, php, jboss

We already have a deployment of JBoss 6.1 application server which hosts a java application written in Spring. Now we are creating another application using HTML+PHP. 
Is it possible to deploy PHP application on existing JBossAS deployment? I have read on internet that to deploy php application I need Jboss native, JbossAS would not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need install JBoss Native to your existing JBoss AS instance + php support. Here in this post is briefly described the process how to do it:

https://community.jboss.org/message/426264#426264

and JBoss Native and PHP support page:

http://www.jboss.org/jbossweb/native/

http://www.jboss.org/jbossweb/downloads/php/